# Remove primary key from a table the references record with foreign key in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

Do I need my `id` column if the unique identifier is the `user_id` foreign key? I dont think I would ever query the `user_profile` by id. The reason is that my User model `has_one :user_profile` and my `user_profile belongs_to :user`

models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user_profile  
end

class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user profile migrations

```
class CreateUserProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_profiles do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddUserReferenceColumnToUserProfilesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :user_profiles, :users, index: false, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Postgres user_profiles table

```
                                          Table "public.user_profiles"
   Column   |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('user_profiles_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name | character varying              |           |          | 
 last_name  | character varying              |           |          | 
 created_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at | timestamp(6) without time zone |           | not null | 
 users_id   | bigint                         |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "user_profiles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_1e573f2ed5" FOREIGN KEY (users_id) REFERENCES users(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mention any attribute of table as primary key like this:

```
create_table :user_profiles, :primary_key => :user_id do |t|
```